# Problem in ble mesh low power node and friend node esp32 wroom

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, mesh-network

I'm studying low power node and friend node functionality in esp32 using sdk version 4.4.2 and an example is on_off server there is menuconfig for feature enable but what are the processes or steps for understanding actual functionality means how can we configure how we can use lpn and friend node and send data?

I'm attempting to use example code with a nrf mesh mobile application, and I'm hoping to use the capabilities of lpn and buddy nodes from the ground up. What steps should I take?

Comment: I'm wondering if the esp32 mesh implementation is even compatible to the nrf mesh mobile application. Are they both implementing the BLE standard for mesh?

Comment: Yes, the ESP32 Mesh implementation and the Nordic nRF Mesh mobile application, if both adhering strictly to the Bluetooth Mesh standard, should be compatible with each other.